# ISO-10646 XFont encoding issue

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, encoding, x11

I'm trying to use `ISO-10646` fixed font in my `X Window` program. It has to support English, Russian and Greek letters but it doesn't. In `xfontsel` window all is OK but in my program only English displays correctly. Using something like `g++ -fexec-charset=ISO-10646 ...` or `g++ -finput-charset=ISO-10646 ...` wasn't helpful. How can I fix it?

---

Test app window screenshot:

[image: Test app window screenshot]

---

xfontsel window screenshot:

[image: xfontsel window screenshot]

---

Test app code:

```
#include <X11/StringDefs.h>
#include <X11/Xaw/Command.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Widget widget = XtInitialize(argv[0], "simple", NULL, 0, &argc, argv);
    XtVaCreateManagedWidget(
        "English Русский ελληνικά", labelWidgetClass, widget,
        XtNfont, XLoadQueryFont(XtDisplay(widget),
            "-Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-Normal--20-200-75-75-C-100-ISO10646-1"
        ), XtNwidth, 500, XtNheight, 100, NULL
    );
    XtRealizeWidget(widget);
    XtMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program uses UTF-8-encoded single byte strings, which is not what Xt/Xaw expects. `-fexec-charset` won't help any.

With pure Xlib (no toolkit) you would use `Xutf8DrawString` and friends, but Xt and Xaw have no provision for that.

Xaw theoretically supports 2-byte encodings of labels with `XtNencoding` set to `XawTextEncodingChar2b`, but I could never make it work with UTF-16.

```
    XChar2b lbl[] = { {0x04, 0x40}, {0x04, 0x43},
                      {0x04, 0x41}, {0x04, 0x41},
                      {0x04, 0x3a}, {0x04, 0x38},
                      {0x04, 0x39}, {0, 0}};

    XtVaCreateManagedWidget(
    "w00t", labelWidgetClass, widget,
    XtNfont, XLoadQueryFont(XtDisplay(widget),
        "-Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-Normal--20-200-75-75-C-100-ISO10646-1"
    ), XtNwidth, 500, XtNheight, 100, 
    XtNencoding, XawTextEncodingChar2b,
    XtNlabel, lbl,
    NULL
);
```

This particular string works. I hope you can figure out how to produce an arbitrary label. However, a null byte at either high or low position terminates the string, so no English text can be displayed with this method.

Perhaps a copy of Xaw on my machine is not up to date. There is a patch that should make it work [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=107683) but I don't know if it's applied on this copy and cannot be bothered to build a patched version from sources. Perhaps you shouldn't rely on it if you want to distribute your code dynamically linked, as not every machine will have an up-to-date Xaw library. This patch was made in 2014.

My advice would be not to rely on i18n abilities of Xaw. Use raw X11 with `Xutf8DrawString`, or a modern toolkit such as Qt or Gtk or FLTK or wxWidgets, which should all work with UTF-8 seamlessly. As the last resort, subclass Xaw widgets as needed and make them work with `Xutf8DrawString`.

**Update** I have checked the source from a Gentoo ebuild which ought to be up to date. The patch is not applied there, there is `strlen` everywhere, `XChar2b` is not working. A typical Xaw code fragment:

```
len = strlen(label);
...
if (len) {
    if (w->label.encoding)
        XDrawString16(XtDisplay(gw), XtWindow(gw), gc,
              w->label.label_x, y, (XChar2b *)label, len / 2);
    else
        XDrawString(XtDisplay(gw), XtWindow(gw), gc,
              w->label.label_x, y, label, len);
}
```

Clearly this cannot possibly have any hope of working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#include <locale.h>`, and call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""); XtSetLanguageProc(NULL, NULL, NULL);` before creating the widget, and add the resource `XtNinternational, True`.

```
#include <X11/StringDefs.h>
#include <X11/Xaw/Command.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Widget widget = XtInitialize(argv[0], "simple", NULL, 0, &argc, argv);
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");
    XtSetLanguageProc(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    XtVaCreateManagedWidget(
        "English Русский ελληνικά", labelWidgetClass, widget,
        XtNfont, XLoadQueryFont(XtDisplay(widget),
            "-Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-Normal--20-200-75-75-C-100-ISO10646-1"
        ), XtNwidth, 500, XtNheight, 100,
        XtNinternational, True,
        NULL
    );
    XtRealizeWidget(widget);
    XtMainLoop();
}
```

Compile with:

```
$CC -o font font.c -lXaw3d -lXt -lX11
```